# Take a line from one csv file and split it into columns for another csv file using powershell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv file that contains lines that I'd like to extract and add as columns to a separate csv file.

This is an example of the contents of the first csv file.

[image]

I want to take everything between the third comma and semi-colon for each one and add them as columns to this csv file.

[image]

My desired output is this. Because there may be multiple servers in the first csv file I'd like to export a csv for each server but I can figure that bit out.

[image]

I've been playing around with the following but I can't figure it out.

```
Import-CSV $CsvTargetPath | ForEach-Object {
$newData = $_

Import-CSV $CsvSourcePath | ForEach-Object {
    $_.AdditionalDisks.split(";") | ForEach-Object {
        $newRecordProperties = [ordered]@{
            $DriveLetter = $_.split(",")[3]
            $Label = $_.split(",")[4]
            $Filesystem = $_.split(",")[5]   
        }
        $newRecord = new-object psobject -Property $newRecordProperties
        Write-Output $newRecord
    }

    $CsvTargetPath | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DriveLetter -Value $DriveLetter -PassThru
    $CsvTargetPath | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Label -Value $Label -PassThru
    $CsvTargetPath | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Filesystem -Value $Filesystem -PassThru
}      
} | Export-CSV $CsvTargetPath -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is the contents of the first csv in plain text.

```
VmName  AdditionalDisks
Server01    90,0,thick,b,sql backup,refs;110,1,thick,d,sql data,refs;60,2,thick,f,sql transaction log,refs;50,3,thin,l,sql audit,refs;30,0,thick,t,sql tempdb data,refs
Server02    90,0,thick,b,sql backup,refs;110,1,thick,d,sql data,refs;60,2,thick,f,sql transaction log,refs;50,3,thin,l,sql audit,refs;30,0,thick,t,sql tempdb data,refs
```

Comment: Please could you edit your question and show us the first 3 or 4 lines of (at least) the first CSV file as **plain text** (copy from notepad) so we don't have to type what you already have available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the second csv file can also hold info for multiple servers (how else would you know the Uuid for each disk?), you could do like below

```
$additionalDiskInfo = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\file1.csv'
$serverInfo         = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\file2.csv'

$additionalDiskInfo | ForEach-Object {
    $server      = $_.VmName
    $targetItems = $serverInfo | Where-Object { $_.VmName -eq $server }
    $extraDisks  = $_.AdditionalDisks -split ';'
    # make sure you don't run into index errors
    $maxItems = [math]::Min($targetItems.Count, $extraDisks.Count)
    # loop through the arrays and output combined objects
    $result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $maxItems; $i++) {
        $n1, $n2, $n3, $driveLetter, $label, $fileSystem = $extraDisks[$i] -split ','
        $targetItems[$i] | Select-Object *, 
                                         @{Name = 'DriveLetter'; Expression = {$driveLetter}},
                                         @{Name = 'Label'; Expression = {$label}},
                                         @{Name = 'FileSystem'; Expression = {$fileSystem}}
    } 
    # now write a new csv file for this server
    $result | Export-Csv -Path ('D:\Test\DiskInfo-{0}.csv' -f $server) -NoTypeInformation
}
```

The resulting csv files would look like this

```
"VMName","Harddisk","Uuid","DriveLetter","Label","FileSystem"
"Server01","Hard disk 2","600C293-7e48-3a63-fb02-cd44df98fe79","b","sql backup","refs"
"Server01","Hard disk 3","600C293-7e48-3a63-fb02-cd44df98f454","d","sql data","refs"
"Server01","Hard disk 4","600C293-7e48-3a63-fb02-cd44df98f10a","f","sql transaction log","refs"
"Server01","Hard disk 5","600C293-7e48-3a63-fb02-cd44df98f483","l","sql audit","refs"
"Server01","Hard disk 6","600C293-7e48-3a63-fb02-cd44df98fced","t","sql tempdb data","refs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
$csv=Import-Csv $CsvSourcePath
$csv|%{
[pscustomobject][ordered]@{
DriveLetter=($_.AdditionalDisks.Split(","))[3]
Label=($_.AdditionalDisks.Split(","))[4]
FileSystem=($_.AdditionalDisks.Split(","))[5]
}}|export-csv $CsvTargetPath -append
```